# pl/sql : aggregate rows into a varchar?

Tags: plsql, multiple-columns, concatenation

```
SELECT concat(concat('m.', COLUMN_NAME), concat(' = mtf.', COLUMN_NAME)) A
 FROM all_tab_columns
where table_name like 'T_EMPLOYEE'
```

and i got the result : [image]

How to aggregate the `AND` and rows into a varchar as the expected result below :

```
m.a_emp_id = mft.a_emp_id AND m.a_emp_name = mft.a_emp_name
AND m.a_emp_sal = mft.a_emp_sal AND m.a_emp_dept = mft.a_emp_dept
AND m.a_emp_status = mft.a_emp_status
```

Comment: The `concat` function is not often used. The usual approach is the concatenation operator `||`. Especially since this removes the need to nest function calls. The first line of your query would be: `SELECT 'm.' || COLUMN_NAME || ' = mtf.' || COLUMN_NAME A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this. It may help.

```
-------------------------------PLSQL Starts-----------------------------------------

set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
lv_cond LONG;
BEGIN
FOR i IN (
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ROWNUM =1
    THEN 'WHERE '
      ||concat(concat('m.', COLUMN_NAME), concat(' = mtf.', COLUMN_NAME))
    ELSE 'AND '
      ||concat(concat('m.', COLUMN_NAME), concat(' = mtf.', COLUMN_NAME))
  END col1
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'EMP_V1') LOOP
lv_cond:=lv_cond||' '||i.col1;
END LOOP;
dbms_output.put_line(lv_cond);
END;

-------------------------------PLSQL Ends-----------------------------------------

SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ROWNUM =1
    THEN 'WHERE '
      ||concat(concat('m.', COLUMN_NAME), concat(' = mtf.', COLUMN_NAME))
    ELSE 'AND '
      ||concat(concat('m.', COLUMN_NAME), concat(' = mtf.', COLUMN_NAME))
  END
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'EMP_V1' ;

---------------------------------OUTPUT---------------------------------------------

COL1
WHERE m.EMPNO = mtf.EMPNO
AND m.ENAME = mtf.ENAME
AND m.JOB = mtf.JOB
AND m.MGR = mtf.MGR
AND m.HIREDATE = mtf.HIREDATE
AND m.SAL = mtf.SAL
AND m.COMM = mtf.COMM
AND m.DEPTNO = mtf.DEPTNO
AND m.NEWADD = mtf.NEWADD
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can i know how to concate into a string that stores all rows? @AvrajitRoy

Comment: I have modified the answer with the PLSQL approach to store it into a variable. You can use VARCHAR2 in place of LONG.

Comment: Hey may I know why I get -15 for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since 11G you can use [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm) function for that.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(
         'm.' || COLUMN_NAME || ' = ' || 'mtf.' || COLUMN_NAME,
         CHR(13) || CHR(10) || 'AND ')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID)  A
FROM all_tab_columns
where table_name like 'T_EMPLOYEE'
```

- I used `||` for varchar concatenation (looks a bit cleaner for me).
- `CHR(13) || CHR(10)` is CRLF
- `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID)` specifies the order in which rows are gathered for concatenation